# Adding overlay to Bootstrap Thumbnail Image on hover within a well

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap well. Within the well I have a thumbnail image. What I am trying to do is whenever i hover over the image, I want there to be a black overlay on-top of the image e.g. rgba(0,0,0,0.5). Currently, this is what I have:

```
.
```

You can see the actual code and current output on my Codepen (it is a little lengthy) : [click here for what I currently have](http://codepen.io/csapty12/pen/mEKKgd)

As you can see from the Pen, when I hover over the image, the overlay occurs, but below the actual image, rather than on the image. Ideally I want this to sit in such a way that when i resize my screen e.g. for mobile phones, the overlay should stay in proportion with the image. I tried with media queries but that was a very poor idea. How can I cause the overlay to sit on-top of the image which in turn would get rid of the excess space at bottom of the well?

Answer (score 1):

To do this you can set display of its parent to `relative` and add both image and the overlay with position `absolute` and top and left `0`; set the overlay opacity to `0` and on mouse over set it to `.5`

```
    .parent{
    position:relative;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    }

.parent img, .parent .overlay{
position:absolute;
left:0;
top:0;
width:100px;
height:100px;
}

.parent .overlay{opacity:0;}
.parent .overlay:hover{opacity:.5;}
```

And the html would be:

```
<div class="parent">
    <img src="image.png" />
    <div class="overlay">
</div>
```

But I recommand another solution that you just give its parent black background and on hover set the opacoty of image to `.5`:

```
.parent{backgound:#000;}
.parent img:hover{opacity:.5}
```

And the html:

```
<div class="parent">
    <img src="image.png" />
</div>
```

Comment: Let me give that a go, because my structure is a little annoying

Comment: Ok. try it and see which one of the solutions suits you

Comment: the second one worked, however, my goal is to get the button to be in the centre of the image when the overlay is placed ontop on-hover, do you know how that can be done?

Comment: yep give the button `{position:absolute; left:50%; top:50%; translate(-50%,-50%); }` of course then the overlay must have position `relative`. and this was another question. you got the answer for this one right?;)

Comment: i did get the answer yes haha! so now i need to get the button to be positioned correctly